# How to redirect to a successful page?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

**What i tried:**

I am trying to setup a basic login system. After user is authenticated, how do I redirect him/her to another page?

*I have tried* using actionRequest.sendRedirect but it does not work either. I get an error.

**This is my code:**

```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String first_name = request.getParameter("first_name");
        String last_name = request.getParameter("last_name");
        String display_name = request.getParameter("display_name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        try{
        //loading driver 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //creating connection with the database 
          Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection
                     ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","password");
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
                  ("insert into User values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, first_name);
        ps.setString(2, last_name);
        ps.setString(3, display_name);
        ps.setString(4, email);
        ps.setString(5, pass);
        int i=ps.executeUpdate();
        if(i>0)
        {
            System.out.println("Registration Successful on backend!");
            actionResponse.sendRedirect("twitterResult.jsp");  **//GIVES ERROR**
        }

        }catch(Exception se)
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }   
      }
```

**Question:**

If user is successfully authenticated (i>0), How do I redirect to another page say home.jsp or some other page?

Please kindly help!

Comment: @JigarJoshi  actionResponse cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your reference should be `response` there is no symbol called `actionResponse`

change it to

```
response.sendRedirect("twitterResult.jsp");
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also use requestdispatcher interface

```
 <%
 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("twitterResult.jsp");
 rd.forward(request, response);
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use forward action to move from one jsp to other

```
  <jsp:forward page="twitterResult.jsp" />
```